# Is it possible to add "skill tags" (tag frames, don't know how to call it) in google doc?

Tags: google-docs

I'd like to list skills on my resume created in google doc like in the image below. Is it possible to create such "tags" and put them easily in desired section?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications. Please extend the description "skill tags". Why don't insert images? Have you tried to use the built-in drawing feature? What about the Smart Chips feature? What about using nested tables?